# Solve A x = b for A in numpy / scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is it possible, using tools available in `numpy.linalg` or `scipy.linalg`, to solve for A in the equation

$$A x = b$$

where $A$, $x$, and $b$ are $n\times n$ matrices ($b$ is a diagonal matrix)? Essentially, I'm trying to "reverse solve" a standard set of linear equations.

Comment: `A = b @ np.linalg.inv(x)`?

Comment: @Julien: That's less efficient and less numerically stable than avoiding the inverse. Inverses are a bit of a trap option in numerical programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply some linear algebra.

```
Ax = b
(Ax)^T = b^T
x^T A^T = b^T
```

Solve for `A^T` with `numpy.linalg.solve`, and transpose:

```
A = numpy.linalg.solve(x.T, b.T).T
```

Comment: I initially tried this, but it didn't seem to work. I may have messed up the equations. Thanks!